# How can I play a MediaPlayer theme song at the background of my app?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an app/game where I would like to have a theme song playing in the background (I am currently doing this with intent service)

The problem is that I want the music to stop when the person "pauses" the applicht ion,  but not stop on new intents

Using onPause () makes the song stop even a new intent is started.

I appreciate your help.

UPDATE:
Fixed it by using a class That is not an activity,

Comment: Can you show what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Java class myservice that extends Service class. This is the code for your myservice class.Add your music file to raw folder in res.

myservice.java

```
package com.khurana.nikhil.servicetest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
public class myservice extends Service {

MediaPlayer mp;
 //MediaStore.Video.Media mt;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music);  //Music file name
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    mp.start();


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    mp.pause();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;

}



}
```

Add this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".myservice"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        >
    </service>
```

On start of your app you can use this..

```
Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,myservice.class);
startService(in);
```

The music will run in the background.
On click of stop button,use this...

```
stopService(in);
```

Comment: Yes that is what I have, but I do not want it on a start of activity to stop. So what I did is use an if to check if I am starting a new activity.